# can't bind scope variables in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-scope

I have these files:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Gestore Anagrafica</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Insert new person</h3>
        <div ng-app="Person" ng-controller="PersonController">
            First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
            Age: <input type="number" ng-model="age"><br>
            <br>
            Full Name: {{fullName()}} <br>
            Is major: {{isMajor()}} <br>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add Person</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/RegistryService.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PersonController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js/RegistryService.js:

```
angular.module('RegistryService', []).

service('registry', function()
{
    this.people = [];

    this.add = function(person)
    {
        people.push(person);
    }
});
```

js/PersonController.js:

```
var app = angular.module('Person', ['RegistryService']);
app.controller('PersonController',['registry', function($scope, registry) {
    $scope.firstName = "testName";
    $scope.lastName = "";
    $scope.age = 20;

    $scope.isMajor = function()
    {
        return $scope.age > 18;
    };

    $scope.add = function()
    {
        registry.add({  'firstName': $scope.firstName,
                        'lastName': $scope.lastName,
                        'age': $scope.age});

    };

    $scope.fullName = function() 
    {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    };
}]);
```

The binding does not occur: when i change the name or the age nothing happens, moreover in the beginning the input are all blank but i expect to see 20 in age and testName in firstName. The browser's console shows no error. Am i missing something?

*Constraints*: the service 'RegistryService' MUST be in another file.

*Question*: 
with these two lines

```
var app = angular.module('Person', ['RegistryService']);
app.controller('PersonController',['registry', function($scope, registry) {
```

i am telling that the module named Person needs something called RegistryService to work, the controller PersonController will use the 'registry' thing located into the RegistryService (hence if i put here something that is not defined into RegistryService is an error). function($scope, registry) is the constructor of the controller that uses a global variable $scope and the variable registry taken from 'RegistryService'. Is my overall understanding of the dependency injection good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to describe `$scope` injection too, since you expect it to be available in your controller function as the first parameter:

```
var app = angular.module('Person', ['RegistryService']);
app.controller('PersonController', ['$scope', 'registry', function($scope, registry) { }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't inject $scope properly

```
app.controller('PersonController',['$scope', 'registry', function($scope, registry) {
```